# Wireshark capture packets on host coming from virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, wireshark

I have a host OS Windows 10 and guest OS Windows 7 on VMWare.

There are 3 types of network connections for VM guest:

```
> 1. Bridged
> 2. NAT
> 3. Host-only
```

Which one should be selected for communication between guest and host OS, so that both guest and host can ping each other?

Also, when using Wireshark, which interface should be chosen in that case?

The available interfaces are:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Choose NAT. 
I think VMnet8 is for NAT on wireshark. 
Ping will be probably blocked because of the windows firewall, so either disable it or allow icmp.